# problems with jQuery from documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please advise me why I can't create this example in my home html file?

Here is an example from the [site](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/) and my html file:

```
<head>
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<script>
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                 "X,Y,Z\n" +
                 "1,0,3\n" +
                 "2,2,6\n" +
                 "8,14,3\n",
                 {
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
                 });          
</script>
<style>
.dygraph-title {
    color: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: add MooTools framework

Comment: The fiddle seems to use the Mootols library. I think that you probably need to add a reference to this library in your code. If not, please verify if the console is throwing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript script must be after div or you need to use document ready to load body first and then script

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<style>
.dygraph-title {
    color: gray;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="graph"></div>
<script>
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                 "X,Y,Z\n" +
                 "1,0,3\n" +
                 "2,2,6\n" +
                 "8,14,3\n",
                 {
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     title: 'dygraphs chart template'
                 });          
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's not a clearest answer. The @Guffa 's answer is more appropriated.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `getElementById` call will return null because the element doesn't exist yet when you run the Javascript code.

Put the code in the load event so that it runs after the page has been parsed:

```
window.onload = function(){

  g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
    ...

};
```

Comment: Just for complement your answer. The question tagged jQuery, so he can solve this putting the code inside the ready event `$(document).ready(function(){ g = new Dygraph... });`

Comment: @rogelio: Yes, it is tagged as such, but the code doesn't seem to use it, and the linked fiddle doesn't include it. Anyway, another alternative is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

One main issue is that your code is running too early.  You are trying to operate on DOM elements before they have even been loaded.  Code running in the `<head>` section cannot yet access elements in the DOM because it has not yet been loaded.

You can move your second `<script>` tag to right before the `</body>` tag and that problem should go away.